# .getJSON in .each function

Tags: jquery, json, each, getjson

I'm looking to nest a .getJSON function in a .each function in order to tie data together from two different requests.

I'm using the Wistia video api, and looking to load videos and their basic info, and also show the `play_count` in the "stats" JSON.

Here's what I've tried, but it's not working-- any suggestions?

```
var projectHashId = "3xom8bku3l";
var wistiaKey = "*hidden*";
var projectStats = "https://api.wistia.com/v1/stats/projects/" + projectHashId +".json?api_password=" + wistiaKey;
var projectMedias = "https://api.wistia.com/v1/projects/" + projectHashId + ".json?api_password=" + wistiaKey;

var total = 0

$.getJSON(projectMedias, function (data) {
    $.each(data.medias, function (i, v) {
        var name = v.name;
        var duration = v.duration;
        var hashedId = v.hashed_id;
        var thumb_orig = v.thumbnail.url;
        var thumb_size = "640x360";
        var thumb = thumb_orig.replace('100x60',thumb_size);
        var description = v.description + " / Created " + v.created;
        var wistiaKey = "*hidden*";
        var mediaStats = "https://api.wistia.com/v1/stats/medias/" + hashedId + ".json?api_password=" + wistiaKey;

        $.getJSON(mediaStats, function (data) {
            var loads = data.load_count;
            var plays = data.play_count;
            var engagement = data.engagement;
        });

        $('#insert-json-videos').append('<div class="col-lg-12 spacer"><div class="video"><img id="video-thumb" src="' + thumb + '"><div class="video-menu"><div class="video-desc"><div class="video-main">' + name + '</div><div class="video-sub"><span id="video-desc">' + description + '</span></div></div><div class="video-stats"><div class="video-main"><a href="stats"><span id="video-views">' + plays + '</span></a></div><div class="video-sub">total views</div></div></div></div></div>');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the variables you are using in the last line will be available only once the second `getJSON` has fulfilled its promise. so put the `append` line inside the second `getJSON` function so that it will be executed only after that promise too is resolved.

```
var total = 0

$.getJSON(projectMedias, function (data) {
    $.each(data.medias, function (i, v) {
        var name = v.name;
        var duration = v.duration;
        var hashedId = v.hashed_id;
        var thumb_orig = v.thumbnail.url;
        var thumb_size = "640x360";
        var thumb = thumb_orig.replace('100x60',thumb_size);
        var description = v.description + " / Created " + v.created;
        var wistiaKey = "*hidden*";
        var mediaStats = "https://api.wistia.com/v1/stats/medias/" + hashedId + ".json?api_password=" + wistiaKey;

        $.getJSON(mediaStats, function (data) {
            var loads = data.load_count;
            var plays = data.play_count;
            var engagement = data.engagement;

            $('#insert-json-videos').append('<div class="col-lg-12 spacer"><div class="video"><img id="video-thumb" src="' + thumb + '"><div class="video-menu"><div class="video-desc"><div class="video-main">' + name + '</div><div class="video-sub"><span id="video-desc">' + description + '</span></div></div><div class="video-stats"><div class="video-main"><a href="stats"><span id="video-views">' + plays + '</span></a></div><div class="video-sub">total views</div></div></div></div></div>');


        });


    })
});
```